# Location of personal dates.txt for MiniMinder on Windows 7

Tags: windows, location

Where is the personal dates.txt located for MiniMinder? A number of reasons: 1) Backup and 2) I'm moving to a new PC and I want to retain the existing dates

Answer (score 0):

1. On the main MiniMinder screen, click "Edit"
2. click on the hammer and wrench button
3. You should be looking at "General Options", if not, click on it.
4. The first item under "General Options" is the location of your Dates.txt file

The default is the program directory.

Fortunately, you can change the location to any directory you want.